# Add a custom field price value on order items in WooCommerce admin

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a custom field on my WooCommerce single product. It sends to the cart fine, it displays on checkout fine, it shows in the order in the dashboard fine.

I need to add a field in order items value. The field content are these :

```
`wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
```

`

The code that i use in my functions.php file:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers');
 function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers() { $column_name = 'Price';
    echo '<th>' . $column_name . '</th>';
}



 add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
    function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {
      $value = wc_price ; 
       if($item['type']=="line_item")
       echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
         }
```

How can I add the field with this calculation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Add a field in order items value

After these code i would like to add a field with taxes (  shippments + product) with these code and Doesn't work.

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers_T');
 function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers_T() { 
    $column_name = 'TAX';
    echo '<th>' . $column_name . '</th>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values_TAX', 10, 3);
    function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values_TAX($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {
    $order_id = get_the_ID();
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $value = wc_price($order->get_tax_totals(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency()));
    if($item['type']=="line_item"){
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers');
 function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers() { 
    $column_name = 'Price';
    echo '<th>' . $column_name . '</th>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
    function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {
    $order_id = get_the_ID();
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $value = wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) );
    if($item['type']=="line_item"){
        echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello it works perfect , and now the next cuestion how can i do it with taxes?

Comment: you want add taxes also?

Comment: Yes I would like to add taxes.

Comment: $value = wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total() + $order->get_total_tax(), array( 'currency' => $order->get_currency() ) ); use this calculation line

Comment: I'm sorry @SeoSiteSoft but i asked somthing wrong, I would like to add a Field with only TAX and not price+shippment+TAXES. Sorry is my bad. And tahnks you very much.

Comment: you want add one more column for Tax?

Comment: Yes ,i would like to add only taxes .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255708/discussion-between-seositesoft-and-victor-daniel-witoszek).

Comment: I would like to change the price shown in the woocomerce email template. The price calculation is: $value = wc_price( $order->get_subtotal() + $order->get_shipping_total(), array( 'currency' => $order ->get_currency() ) ); how can i do it?